# Exporting Crystal Report into PDF causes a freeze - Vb.Net2003

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have an application developed with Vb.Net 2003 and using Crystal Reports 11 used to preview many statistical reports.

I always preview any report successfully, but when exporting some of the reports (not all) into PDF using the built-in export functionality in the report viewer control, the application freezes forever.

So, I need to know if there is any report object (textobject, Picture, Chart, line, box, etc..) that might not be able to be exported into PDF, and I think this type of object is only found in some of my reports and that's why I face this problem only with some of the reports and not all of them.

Comment: Do you have the latest service pack for CR 11 installed?

Comment: What is the latest service pack of CR 11 and where to get it?

Comment: Try here: http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/service_packs/crystal_reports_en.asp

Comment: Thank you Mark.. I think there is a lot of service packs and I need to know which is exactly related to my issue.. I have Crystal Report 11.0.3300.0, so which installation I should use that will fix my problem...

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason this happens is that not all the variables you use in the report are filled. So make sure of that. Otherwise you should get an error on the object you use. Do you get an error on exporting?

Comment: Thank you Cerveser... I think that empty objects may generates error when previewing the crystal report, but it may has no effect when exporting the previewed report into pdf.

Comment: I got no errors, only my computer freeze when trying to export the report into pdf....