# Exporting Crystal Report XI into PDF Freeze - Vb.Net2005

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have an application developed with Vb.Net 2005 and Crystal Report XI used to preview many statistical reports.

I always preview any report successfully, but when exporting any report that contains a Chart into pdf using the built-in export functionality in the report viewer control, the application freezes forever.

While when exporting any report that does not contain any chart into PDF, it exported successfully and with no errors. So, I need to know if there is a some way / Solution / workaround that I could use to fix my issue and let my export process continue successfully.

Comment: does it export ok from the report desinger?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exporting Crystal Report into PDF freeze - Vb.Net2003](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495434/exporting-crystal-report-into-pdf-freeze-vb-net2003)

Comment: @MD-Tech: It is exported successfully from the report designer but not from the application at runtime.

@MArk: I think that this post contain a lot of updates and modification that can`t be merged with another one...thanks for being concentrated....

Answer (score 0):

For starters, make sure you have the latest service packs for the runtime engine you're using. You can get them from SAP.com.

http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=56787567

or if you want an alternate commercial product, check out http://www.reportrunner.com

Comment: Please can you be more precise...I`m sure you could drive me with a good solution here...please advise me more...

Comment: @Davidg I added download links to my original reply